# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'chat', объясните пожалуйста в чем проблема?

Tags: python, telebot, python-telegram-bot

```
import telebot
import time
import requests


api_key = "xxxxx"
bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxxx')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    keyboard = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True)
    keyboard.row('Vkontakte', 'Telegram ID')
    keyboard.row('Обо мне', '/weather')
    keyboard.row('Сайт ITHUB', 'Часто используемые ресурсы')
    keyboard.row('/help', '/photo')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Добро пожаловать!\nС помощью клавиатуры выберите нужное Вам действие.' , reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
def weather(message):
    bot.reply_to(message.chat.id, "Введи название города, чтобы узнать погоду.")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_weather)

def get_weather(message):
    city = message.text
    url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}&units=metric"  # API-запрос к OpenWeatherMap
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    try:
        temp = response['main']['temp']
        feels_like = response['main']['feels_like']
        descr = response['weather'][0]['description']
        wind_speed = response['wind']['speed']
        humidity = response['main']['humidity']
        # Формирование сообщения с погодой
        weather_message = f"Погода в городе {city.capitalize()}:\n\nТемпература: {temp}°C\nОщущается как: {feels_like}°C\nСкорость ветра: {wind_speed} м/с\nВлажность: {humidity}%"
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, weather_message)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите новый город или отправьте команду /start")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_weather)  # Вызов функции для следующего город
    except KeyError:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Город не найден. Попробуйте ввести другой город или отправьте команду /start")
```

Бот выполняет все функции, которые в нём заложены, но при вызове команды /weather выдаёт ошибку: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'chat'

Comment: bot.reply_to(message, "Введи название города, чтобы узнать погоду.") Traceback для лучшего понимания вашей проблемы выкладывате полностью

Comment: Спасибо, помогло Ваше решение, но теперь когда ввожу /start он сначала пишет, что город не найден, и только после повторной отправки команды /start он возвращается в главное меню

Comment: Для фунция get_weather командa /start это city='/start' название города